# Where exactly is my code going

Tags: bamboo

I am bamboo noob. I start off with a git check out and it succeeds.  I'd like to see exactly where it is putting my code.  I cannot access the actual machine bamboo is running on but I have admin rights for the bamboo server. Is there any way I can see the code bamboo brought down?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible. Atlassian sells a different product, [Fisheye](https://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/overview), for viewing source code.

If you are interested in the location of the checked out source, all the path information is available in Bamboo Administration -> System information -> Bamboo paths.